# ERR: while creating a pipeline between github actions and vercel (not in development)

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, vercel, cicd, react-scripts

I am trying to create a pipeline ( connecting my github repo with vercel ) so that any changes made will automatically run set of actions (like testing ) and then get deployed
basically CI-CD

[git hub action log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYHgw.jpg)

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"deploy": "vc --cwd build --prod --yes --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN"
```

},

*the above is my package.json*

**ERR message in github action Error! Command "react-scripts build" exited with 127**

```
on: [push]
jobs:
build-app:
  runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
  env:
    VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
    VERCEL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
    VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2 #we are USEing this action provided by github which clones the repo
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: "18.8.0"
    - run: tree #this is bash command
    - run: node -v
    - name: install node modules
      run: yarn
    - name: installing react-scripts
      run: npm install --save react react-dom react-scripts
    - name: Build the project in the cloud mostly azure
      run: yarn build
    - name: Sets the vercel env
      run: |
        cd build
        mkdir .vercel
        cd .vercel
        touch project.json
        echo "{\"projectId\":\"$VERCEL_PROJECT_ID\",\"orgId\":\"VERCEL_ORG_ID\"}" > project.json
    - name: Deploying the project on vercel
      run: yarn deploy #see deploy cmd in package.json
    - name: setup finish #name is used to name the run cmd
      run: echo "done"
test-app:
  needs: build-app #test-app is dependendant on the build app
  runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
  steps:
    - run: echo "end to end testing using cypress"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check Vercel logs, as suggested in your job log.
BTW, are you able to deploy manually, using this 'vc ....' command?

Comment: Yes I am able to deploy manually

Comment: So I suggest to check Vercel logs